# API на ASP .NET Core в Docker перестает обрабатывать запросы

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, docker, redis

Есть два экземпляра api написанные на ASP.NET Core и запущенные внутри Docker-контейнера на ubuntu 16, перед ними есть балансировщик нагрузки nginx.

Периодически один из экземпляров api перестает отвечать на произвольные запросы от балансировщика нагрузки, причем он отвечает, но периодически перестает, то есть полного зависания не происходит. Лечится это перезагрузкой контейнера api.

Из того что я смог заметить. Зависший контейнер api после посылки ему команды restart, перезапускается дольше чем тот который не зависал.

Подскажите в какую сторону копать что бы диагностировать неисправность?

**UPDATE**

Проблема локализована но не решена. api не отвечает когда ходит в редис-кэш `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis, Version=2.2.0.0` но судя по TCPDUMP обмен пакетами между api и Redis сервером идёт в штатном режиме, такое ощущение что проблема в библиотеке.

Comment: `у меня есть какая то программа, которая как то работает. Я её запускаю на виртуалке и вызываю из другой программы. И с этой программой появляются какие то ошибки - они тормозит. В чем может быть прблема?` по идее в чем угодно.

Comment: @tym32167 я могу добавить контекста,  подскажите что можно добавить для большей ясности?

Comment: неу, например, логгирование в ваши сервисы, результаты их профилирования, возможно теста под нагрузкой, информации о том, становятся они недоступны только для вашей прокси или для любых звпросов, описания что они вообще делают и гле могут быть узкие места, информцию о том, как вы сами боролись с багом и что накопаоли.

Comment: Сервисы не делают ничего особенного там api которая собирает вью модели по запросу пользователей или сохраняют результаты кидая их в шину. Иногда ходят в базу напрямую используя EF. Где могут быть узкие места понятия не имею, вроде все места одинаковые.Из того что вы написали я пробовал тесты под нагрузкой и они не приводят к таким результатам. Спасибо за совет, я не делал части того что вы описали, можно пока закрыть вопрос, до момента как я проведу профилирование сревиса(кстати я не знаю как это делать на бою) и проверю доступность api не от прокси а от когото рядом.

Comment: Как минимум добавьте логи и трассируйте ход запроса, чтбы понять, на каких стадиях запрос тормозит

Comment: @tym32167 логи в консоль пишутся, но глядя на них видно что как будто запрос вообще не приходит... по крайней мере в логах он не отображается. Тем не менее как я уже писал выше перезапуск контейнера решает проблему.

Comment: может проблема в связке между контейнером и вашим nginx?

Comment: @tym32167 в ходе проведенной проверки было установлено что если идти в   api напрямую, минуя nginx, то все работает нормально. Видимо проблема как вы говорите в связке. Nginx посылает запрос не получает ответ и перенаправляет запрос на вторую api. Как вы думаете что тут можно еще сделать?

Comment: к сожалению, я nginx в глаза никогда не видел, потому ничего не могу про него посоветовать :)

Comment: @tym32167 вообщем то что я писал выше это было заблуждение. Я зашёл внутрь контейнера и cURL'ом попытался сделать запрос но api на него не отвечает.

Comment: Ну вообще настройки ip и dns могут быть разные снаружи контейнера и внутри. Когда вы делаете биндинг айпи адреса в докер контейнере, Вы указываете внутренний и внешний адреса, у вас на внутренний не отзывается сервис или внешний?

Comment: @tym32167 проблема локализована но не решена. api не отвечает когда ходит в редис-кэш `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis, Version=2.2.0.0` но судя по TCPDUMP обмен пакетами между api и redis сервером идёт в штатном режиме, такое ощущение что проблема в библиотеке.

Comment: Снимите дамп с висящего процесса и посмотрите, на чем именно висит.

Comment: @PashaPash подскажите как это можно сделать, просто этот баг проявляется редко и его невозможно симитировать в IDE среде.

Comment: посмотрите https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/xplat-minidump-generation.md#configurationpolicy и https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/blob/master/documentation/debugging-coredump.md и https://www.raydbg.com/2018/Debugging-Net-Core-on-Linux-with-LLDB/. Под докером есть особенности - но идея та же - запускаете bash в том же контейнере, через docker exec, дампите (дамп большой, будет тупить), вытягиваете наружу и дебагаете.

Comment: @PashaPash похоже на какую то магию, понятного в этих инструментах пока мало но если что будем разбираться, спасибо.

Comment: Еще есть вариант поставить в контейнер vsdbg и цеплять отладчик удаленно: https://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2019-04-04-debugging-dotnet-in-docker-with-vscode/ - если есть более-менее прямой сетевой доступ к хостингу